# How to Add "Checked Out to Me" to Home page

Tags: 2013

I would like to add a field on the HOME page of "Files checked out to me" so that users can see what they have checked out.

Comment: Are the files stored in more than one document library?

Answer (score 1):

Create a view with filter as "Checked Out To " to [Me]. This should give you desired results.

Comment: that will work if no sub-sites are being used

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Relevant Document web-part.It is inside Content Rollup category

[image]

When you edit a Relevant Documents web part properties, you will find the following options under "Data":

- Include documents last modified by me
- Include documents created by me
- Include documents checked out to me

**Third option will display all documents checked out to the currently logged in user from within that sub web(not entire site collection)**